# PHP: What is the real meaning of an index in an indexed array?

Tags: php, arrays, function, debugging

Say, we make an array like this:

```
$arr = Array
(
            2 => 'c',
            1 => 'b',
            0 => 'a'
);
```

When you pass it to array_pop():

```
array_pop($arr);
```

And the "last" element would be poped off, which has the index of zero!!

```
print_r($arr);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [2] => c
    [1] => b
)
```

So, what's the purpose of index?
Isn't it just a different way of saying "numeric keys of associative arrays"?

Is it only PHP dose so, or all the languages treat arrays like this?

Comment: in the real world, you would probably never use an array like that.

Comment: php did exactly what you told it to do, stored those values, in that order, keys be damned. If you want the keys to match some human logical order in your head, run ksort() on it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not all languages do this, but PHP does, because PHP is a little weird. It implements arrays more or less like dictionaries. PHP does offer some functions like `ksort` though, which let you sort the array by *key*.

And that's what this is: a *key*. An array has indexes as well, so what you got, is an array where item `2` has key `0`. And that's where the confusion <strike>starts</strike> continues.

*PHP: a fractal of bad design* has a whole [chapter about arrays](http://eev.ee/blog/2012/04/09/php-a-fractal-of-bad-design/#arrays). Interesting reading material. :)

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this behavior is because [arrays in PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) are actually **unordered maps**.

Because of this, don't think of accessing the arrays in terms of *indexes*, think of it in terms of *keys*.  Keys can be numbers and they can be strings, but the result is the same; you're still using a map, not a true "array".

Once you accept that fact, you'll understand why PHP includes functions like ksort() for sorting an array by keys and why array_pop() doesn't always remove the highest key value.

Answer (score 1):

It's a PHP thing. Other languages usually provide other structures to provide what is the default behaviour for arrays on PHP. JavaScript for instance will always sort the array:

```
    a = [];
    > []
    a[1] = 'a';
    > "a"
    a[2] = 'b';
    > "b"
    a[0] = 'c';
    > "c"
    a
    > ["c", "a", "b"]
```

In Java you would need to use a Hash Map or something else to do Associative Arrays. PHP handles data structures more loosely than other languages.

The index allows you to identify and access the elements of the array.

Answer (score 1):

the reason is simple `HashTables`.

in php internal functions often use `HashTables`. basically an array is some data in memory and like in `C` - an array index can only hold integer values but not in `php`.

php solves this with hashtables. if you asign a index example `foo` this value is not directly assigned  as `foo` it gets hashed and maybe end internal as `000000000111` and other hash functions.

so php doesn't work directly with your assigned value and this is the reason why you can set an array index like `0` as last index element. internal php work with hashtables that have a "list" with values which index value is assigned to which position in the array.